# Is there a fast method of changing directory to a symbolic links parent or source?

Tags: linux, command-line, symbolic-link

Say I have folder stucture:

```
|- dir1/
|  |-  sub1/
|
|- dir2/
   |- sub1link -> /dir1/sub1/
```

and my current working directory is sub1link, is there a quick way to either:

- change directory to link source parent (i.e something similar to `cd ..` but take the user to /dir1/
- change directory to link source (i.e switch from `/dir2/sub1link/` straight to `/dir1/sub1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cd -P ..`.  Run `help cd` for more details.  `-L` follows symlinks and is usually the default behavior, whereas `-P` uses the physical directory structure.